# how to add solr to run on startup?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, java, solr

I asked this question before, but I think I got answers that were cron job type answers.

I want the solr service to startup if I reboot my computer, and I also want it to run by itself instead of me opening up cmd.exe and running it manually, and then having to close my terminal connection (not log off as that will close it).

What options do I have?

I am on windows server 2008, IIS7 running a asp.net application that uses solr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a service: http://www.tacktech.com/display.cfm?ttid=197

Basically this should allow you to create a service, point it at the exe and then use services.msc to control it like a normal service. I.e. Automatic start and so on.

What command do you currently run to start solr?

Comment: java -jar start.jar using cmd.exe

Comment: Put those commands in .bat file and then you might also need to convert the .bat file to an exe with this utilty: Bat2Exe http://www.computerhope.com/dutil.htm